# why the dataSnapshot.getValue() is Hashmap instead of ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

when I'm trying to run this code it fails because it tries to cast HashMap to List view, which probably means the class of the value **is** HashMap.

```
final DatabaseReference dayRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("days").child(day.getYear())
            .child(day.getMonth()).child(day.getDayOfMonth());

    //Reference initialize for writing
    final DatabaseReference morningsRef = dayRef.child("need morning");

     morningsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (student.needMorning){
                ArrayList<Student> morningStudents = (ArrayList<Student>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                morningsRef.setValue(morningStudents);
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("TAG", databaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });
```

but then i tried to run this code:

```
morningsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (student.needMorning){
                ArrayList<Student> morningStudents = (ArrayList<Student>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                morningsRef.setValue(morningStudents);
                Toast.makeText(context,morningStudents.getClass().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("TAG", databaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });
```

The toast said:

> class java.util.ArrayList

[this is a sample of my JSON:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY8L6.png)

What is wrong here?

Comment: The type of object returned by getValue() is going to be dependent on the data at the location you queried.  Can you show what that is?

Comment: BTW, you can't get a strongly typed generic collection using getValue() with no arguments.  If the data is going to be an array, it is only safe to cast it to ArrayList<Object>.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i added a screenshot of my database structure

Comment: How is `morningsRef` defined?